# Infragistics control XamDataTreeNode IsExpanded regiter to PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, infragistics

I'm using Infragistics control called XamDataTree.
XamDataTree holds a collection of XamDataTreeNode.
After inserting all XamDataTreeNode items to XamDataTree.
I am doing for-each on the collection and changing the IsExpanded property of each one of the nodes. 
As a result of that, Infragitics code behind register node.PropertyChanged.
This registration cause to memory leak because there is no unregistered operation.

Does any one knows why unregistered doesn't being called ?

thanks

Comment: I think you are right there is indeed a memory leak in the infragistics code, we were using Infragistics 14.1 without any issues, since upgrading to 15.1 there are problems in the "removed" Nodes being kept alive by a bound object with the PropertyChanged event. When a property is changed in that object the control gives an null reference exception. Did you contact Infragistics Support ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a memory leak due to the control you should [contact Infragistics support](https://www.infragistics.com/my-account/submit-support-request/) with an example so they can address the issue.

If the memory leak is only specific to your application then you should post code that you are using as part of your question so others can see what is being done.